# how to do the ssh to the docker

Tags: docker, ssh, docker-machine

I am new to the docker. I want to install git and ruby in the docker container through ssh to that. To begin with I started with downloading docker.dmg and installed that in my local mac machine.

```
docker-machine version 0.12.0, build 45c69ad
```

but

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

It does not return anything. So I don't have any name for the docker. So its difficult to get the ip and ssh to that.
Once I am able to ssh then I can install git/ruby etc from command line.

Comment: You have to run a docker container first. try `docker run hello-world` to get started. I'd recommend looking at some docker tutorials if you are new to the concept of containers.

Comment: I already ran that. docker run hello-world

Hello from Docker!
This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly. But it does not say the name of the docker. I tried with the name 'default' but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get your docker running, you can run bash from the command line with the following:

```
docker exec [docker-name] -it bash
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Docker in your local then you do not need to ssh. You just need to run some containers.

But if you really need to ssh inside a container then you can do:

`docker exec -it <container_id> bash` but for alpine images, `docker exec -it <container_id> ash`

Comment: My target is that if I am able to do it then I would set up this in one of our remote machine . So I need to do the ssh.

Comment: Could you be more specific with the 'it' and 'this'?

Comment: If I am able to do the ssh then I would set up the docker in one of our remote machine and ssh to that and install git/ruby etc

Comment: I think you are off the topic, I think what you want is to ssh in one of your servers like `ssh -x root@1.92.168.1.1`. Install `docker ` there and then run some  containers on that server

Comment: After installing the docker , how to create the container. I tried with "docker create dashboard" (i.e dashboard is just a name I want to give)
Unable to find image 'dashboard:latest' locally
Error response from daemon: repository dashboard not found: does not exist or no pull access

Comment: Seems like you are not knowledgeable on how `Docker` works. What do you want to do with that dashboard? Is that a python app? nodejs? Try to be more detail on what you want to do

Comment: This is a ruby app. ( ruby + sinatra gem). I need to run this in a docker container.

Comment: I'm not a ruby developer so I cannot completely assist you. But I can give a sample docker command for ruby like `docker run -it --name my-running-script my-ruby-app` as specified in their official image here https://hub.docker.com/_/ruby/. I recommed you take a look at the link and follow their instructions